# How to set format to a JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, fractions, jformattedtextfield

I want to use a `JFormattedTextField` that can input fraction numbers. As Java doc specifies its format should set within the constructor. But I’m using NetBeans IDE,  the constructor of the `JFormattedTextField` is a generated code , so I don’t know how to specify a format.

And if you can please direct me to a helpful tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize the creation code of a Swing element in NetBeans, right-click the element and select *Customize code...*. In the following pop-up, click the drop-down menu next to the code snippet and select *Custom creation*. Then you can specify the code yourself as such:

```
DecimalFormat df = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
// do some manipulation to the DecimalFormat object if desired
jFormattedTextField = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField(df);
```